# How to initialize base class property once instead of passing it from all derived classes?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, refactoring

I have a small library where I am performing 1 long running operation and based on that operation,I am saving some data inside database tables.Now this is small library which does not include alot of database tables operation hence I have used Ado.net to manage data access layer.

I have created base class where I have put Connection string and Ado.net commands execution.

I have 3-4 class with some methods performing insert,update and delete but the problem is I have to pass connection string to each of this 4 class whenever I am creating the object of this class.

**Code :**

```
 internal abstract class BaseRepo
    {
        private readonly string connectionString;

        protected int TestId;
        protected int VariantId;


        public BaseRepo() { }

        protected BaseRepo(string connection)
        {
            this.connectionString = connection;
        }

        internal virtual void ExecuteQuery(string query,
            IList<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        internal virtual void ExecuteQueryWithTransaction(SqlConnection connection,SqlTransaction transaction, string query,
            IList<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection, transaction))
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        internal virtual int ExecuteScalar(string query,
            IList<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }
                    var data = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (data == null)
                        return 0;
                    return (int)data;
                }
            }
        }
    }


internal class VariantRepo : BaseRepo
    {
        public VariantRepo(string connectionString,int testId,int variantId) : base(connectionString)
        {
            TestId = testId;
            VariantId = variantId;
        }

        public VariantRepo(testId) : base(connectionString)
        {
           TestId = testId;
        }
        public void DeleteVariantData()
        {
            string query = "";
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", TestId));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VariantId", VariantId));
            ExecuteQuery(query, parameters);
        }
    }

internal class RegionRepo : BaseRepo
    {
        public RegionRepo(string connectionString, int variantId) : base(connectionString)
        {
            VariantId = variantId;
        }
        public int GetRegionIdByVariantId()
        {
            string query = "";
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", VariantId));
            return ExecuteScalar(query, parameters);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have 4 class here and from each of this class I have to pass connection string to base class :

1) `VariantRepo`

2) `RegionRepo`

3) `CategoryRepo`(not shown but it is same like above 2)

4) `TestRepo`(not shown but it is same like above 2).

So there are 2 things that I would like to address here :

1) It is possible to design base class in a way that I have to pass connection string only once and not for each of the 4 concrete classes?

2) I want to hide this below dirty logic(`Sql parameter creation code`) behind some class to have better readability because I have to do this at so many places:

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", TestId));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VariantId", VariantId));
```

I thought to have base class as concrete class but than having base class as abstract class makes more sense I guess that is why I have marked base class as abstract.

Can someone please help me to design this in better way?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not the answer you are looking for, but I would use a config file, which I'd store the connstring in, and then  set it as a static variable in base class.

Comment: I already have a config file where I am getting the connection string and than passing connection string all along with this 4 concrete class

Answer (score 0):

What you're explicitly asking for is not possible. Each derived class has to be initializable by using its ctor, so every ctor has to take in the connection string one way or another.
You could:

- Use a factory class that takes a connection string in its ctor once and then returns repo objects initialized with that connection string, as in

```
class RepoFactory
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public RepoFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public VariantRepo GetVariantRepo(int testId, int variantId) => 
        new VariantRepo(_connectionString, testId, variantId);

    ...
}
```

- Use Dependency Injection throughout your code, create a `ConnectionStringProvider` class, or similar, that will have a get-only property `ConnectionString` (maybe read that value from a config file) and then inject it into your various repos.

Comment: Is it good to take a static property inside the base class and initialize it inside a constructor?

Comment: Changing a static property inside a constructor sounds like an assault&battery on OOP.

Comment: I mean something like this in base class :  private static readonly string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;

Comment: If your `ConfigurationManager` is static then it'll work.